# How can I deploy a new web application to a subdirectory of an IIS site and not have to click "Convert To Application"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, build-automation

I'm trying to write an automated deployment application that runs on one box but deploys to a remote QA server. Basically each time a branch is created in source control my automated deployment tool will deploy the application. Right now the code all deploys but IIS doesn't like the nested web.config files unless I use the "Convert to Application" function.

Notice in the below screenshot that for the Test-Site which was just created for the new "Test-Site" branch that the folders "Analyze", "Investigate", "Measure" and "Score" aren't applications like the RevECurrent and RevENew have above for those folders. **Without actually clicking "Convert To Application" for each folder how do I make the web.config files not generate errors whenever I deploy a new subdirectory like "Test-Site"?**

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with deployment. It's a standard ASP.NET issue with web.config hierarchy. Answer: you can't do what you want, without either applications or a separate site for each "branch".

Comment: This question seems better suited to http://serverfault.com as it is related to application deployment, not application development.

Comment: I would argue that through development, he could use the System.Web.Management namespace to program something to do this during his auto-deployment process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [System.Web.Administration namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it will allow you to interact with IIS. I have used it to add/remove bindings, add sites, etc... I would assume it would let you create application folders under a Web Site as well.

Comment: Thanks. This put me on the right track. I believe I need to use the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace which is for IIS7 and using the ServerManager object seems to allow me to connect to a remote server. Thanks

Comment: yup, that's the correct one. Sorry about that, glad I got you down the right track however. Good luck with your project.

Comment: updated my answer for future-comers to this question, not to lead them in the wrong direction.